# Simple post to a Facebook page wall as authed API user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We're making a digital radioplayer where listeners can send messages to the studio. The idea is that the user will fill in a textarea on the website, pushes the button and the message gets posted on the studio's Facebook wall where the DJ's are monitoring it.

This works perfectly fine for user walls but when I try to post to a page wall, I get this error:

```
"(#200) The user has not granted the application the permission to automatically publish feed stories"
```

Am I forgetting something? Or is this impossible? Does the user need to like the page? Or is there a setting needed to be changed as the page Admin?

I created a test page, I liked it and been testing with my account. I also checked the box "Anyone can post on the timeline of x Page". But no help.

Here is the simplefied code:

```
function facebookPost(target,content) {
    FB.api('/'+target+'/feed','post',{
        message:message
    },function(res){
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

I've been working with the API for a while now, but this one really scratched my head.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I discovered that the error only raises when the page admin is posting on his own page. When I add 'manage_pages' to the perms I don't get the error but the post is in name of the page, like a status update.**

**So it works for other users, but only if they haven't 'liked' the page before posting, else the page admin is not notified of a new post, he cannot see it, only the user and his friends can. (this is a problem because the DJ's must see those posts)**

**Has anyone experience this kind of behaviour before?**

Comment: Which permissions did you request from the user?

Comment: only publish_stream, like I said it works fine if 'target' is an user ID. I also discovered the error only raises when a page admin tries to post something on his own page I will edit the question

Comment: better use publish_actions instead of publish_stream. does not open a second permission dialog.

Comment: Did you try to set the "from" and "to" properties of the post? I.e. "from" the users ID and "to" the page id?

Answer (score 0):

For those coming to this page with the same error, I found that you need publish_stream not publish_actions.

Even though the Facebook docs say that publish_actions replaces publish_stream. When I did a FB.login for publish_actions, it passed, but the post got the same error as the author of the post.

When I requested publish_stream, it presented me a dialogue to request new permissions, and after I hit ok, the post the worked.

The code I used:

```
params={message: "Your message on the wall."}

FB.login(function(response) { console.log(response) }, {scope:'publish_stream'})
FB.api('/<The Page ID>/feed', 'post', params, function(response) { console.log(response)  });
```